# Getting Image from host and show it on broswers in spring boot

Tags: spring

i have this code for saving an image on filesystem from a url and it works fine:

```
@GetMapping("/prova/{id}")
public void getImage(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
    String url= "http://localhost:80/" + id;
   
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverts = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverts.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

    RestTemplate restTemplate1 = new RestTemplate(messageConverts);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate1.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class);

    if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
     
       Files.write(Paths.get(uploadFolderPath + "/" + id), response.getBody()); show(id)}
```

Now i want show in the broswer this image that i saved on filesystem, at the same moment.I tried using `@ResponseBody byte[] show`
to show the image on broswer but it's not working, the page keep being just white. The method who should show is the `show(id)`
Any suggestions how implement the method "show" pls?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach of the image download is to directly work against a response object and mimic a pure Servlet implementation, and its demonstrated using the following snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/prova/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public void getImageAsByteArray(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/uploadFolderPath/" + id);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Issuing the following request will render the image in a browser:

`http://localhost:8080/<base_url>/prova/{id}`

The implementation is fairly straightforward using `IOUtils` from the `org.apache.commons.io` package.

Comment: i get error "Cannot resolve symbol 'servletContext'" using Intellij idea

Comment: Check if you have autowired the context. 
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;